# TestNG: Creating unique, testable data for @Tests

Tags: java, testng

In TestNG, I have many tests across many classes that require a page and/or article and possibly other data setup.  This data needs to be unique (AKA, Test1 and Test2 both require an article, but they have to work on identical but separate articles so they don't conflict with one another).  I am providing the article name/page name via dataProviders.

Here's what I've tried/considered:

- `@dependsOnMethods`.  Won't work, because it can't be cross-class.
- `@dependsOnGroups`. This has the problem of creating a single article for all tests to work off of.
- `@beforeMethods`. I can't use this because I can't pass in data
- `@factory`. I am unable to use this because I am using a company-wide solution that currently uses this to pass around the webDriver and has code behind the scenes that uses it
- Creating a method that the tests call at the beginning, .  This is what I am currently doing, and it works fine, but when that method fails, TestNG will still run the setup methods (which will then fail, and cause 8-10 failures for 1 bug, and wasted testing time)

Basically I need a way to throw a SkipException in a function if it has previously failed, without using the 4 annotations above.

EDIT:  I realized that this question isn't quite complete.  I pass in two things to each of the functions: A role, and a name for the newly created page/article/other stuff.  If I run the same method twice with different names but the same roles passed in, and it fails, then the second time, it should just skip it...however, I may be testing it with a role that doesn't have enough permissions, which would cause an exception to be thrown, but that doesn't mean I don't want to run it with other roles.